# Fetch multiple records from Database without refreshing page

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I have been searching for a while now and seen a lot of post about this subject, but I can't figure out why my script isn't working.

I would like to fetch multiple records from my DB by clicking on a div. I have 2 files: test.html and test.php.

I checked the output that test.php returns that's oke, also checked if it is valide json which is also the case. I think the problem is how I handle the returned data in test.html

test.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                "use strict";
                $('.clickable').click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "test.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                            $.each(obj, function (index, value) {
                                $('#output').append(index + " : " + value.id + " " + value.column1 + " " + value.column2);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
        <style>

            .clickable { 
                cursor: pointer; 
                color: blue; 
            }

            .clickable:hover, .clickable.hover { 
                text-decoration: underline; 
            }

            .clickable:active{ 
                color: black; 
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3><div class="clickable">Click here</div></h3>
        <div id="output">Text will come</div>


    </body>
</html>
```

test.php

```
<?php

$user = "root";
$pass = "***";
$host = "localhost";
$dbdb = "testDB";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbdb);
if(!$connect)
{
    trigger_error('Error connection to database: '.mysqli_connect_error());
}

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `testtable`"); 

$json = array();

while($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $json[] = $array;

} 

echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Output test.php:

```
[{"id":"1","column1":"Mike","column2":"23"},{"id":"2","column1":"math","column2":"56"},{"id":"3","column1":"Peter","column2":"78"},{"id":"4","column1":"Alice","column2":"32"},{"id":"5","column1":"John","column2":"26"},{"id":"6","column1":"Mark","column2":"11"},{"id":"7","column1":"Paul","column2":"47"},{"id":"8","column1":"Phil","column2":"90"}]
```

Comment: Have you checked any javascript errors in your console? Do you receive the data? If so, your loop is incorrect.

Comment: @randomizer I'm not sure how to check javascript errors in my concole, im working in a text editor. I did check it at jslint and now i have 0 erros but my script still isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
$.each(obj, function(index, value)){
       $('#output').append(index+" : "+value);
}
```

to

```js
var data = '[{"id":"1","column1":"Mike","column2":"23"},{"id":"2","column1":"math","column2":"56"},{"id":"3","column1":"Peter","column2":"78"},{"id":"4","column1":"Alice","column2":"32"},{"id":"5","column1":"John","column2":"26"},{"id":"6","column1":"Mark","column2":"11"},{"id":"7","column1":"Paul","column2":"47"},{"id":"8","column1":"Phil","column2":"90"}]';

var obj = JSON.parse(data);
$.each(obj, function(index, value){
  $('#output').append(value.id + ": " + value.column1 + " " + value.column2 + "<br />");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

You are not closing the `$.each` call correctly and you have to select the properties you want to append.

Comment: Ty, I did forget to close the loop. sadly it didn't fix my problem

Comment: When I change that it is working, so can I assume the problem is somewhere in returning the data and resieving the data? If so how can i find the problem.

Comment: @PHPhil Do not add the `data`, like i did. This is just an example if your `ajax` call is working you should be fine.

Comment: No idea why , but when I changed `$.each` to a `for()` loop it worked. I could only get the `$.each` to work if I altered my json and put it al inside a wrapper. and called it like `$.each(data.wrapper, function(index, value){` anyway ty for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$.each` isn't written correctly. There is a closing bracket `)` that is not required.

```
                                  |
                                  |
                                  v
$.each(obj, function(index, value)){
   $('#output').append(index+" : "+value);
})
```

so try changing it to this:

```
$.each(obj, function (index, value) {
    $('#output').append(index + ": " + value);
});
```